# Going from Newark airport to Philadelphia airport

Tags: airport-transfer, ewr, phl

I will need go from Newark airport to Philadelphia Airport.

What is best way to do that trip?

I will land at Newark around 9 PM

Comment: How much time do you have?

Comment: How much time?  Money?

Comment: Hi and welcome to [travel.se]. [We don't really do recommendations here on Travel.SE.](/help) Moreover, "best" is a subjective term: what might be best for you might not be best for me. Hence why I am voting to close as opinion-based. Please take the site [tour] and read our [help] to gain a better understanding on how this site works.

Comment: @JoeErNano Is this question being put on hold after 4 1/2 years of being posted and answered because I posted an answer? I find it suspicious that no one has had a problem with this question until now.

Answer (score 3):

If by best you mean the quickest and easiest, reserving a car/limo service to pick you up at your arrivals terminal at Newark Airport and drop you off of at the precise location you require at the Philadelphia Airport would be the best. 
Going rates (2018) for a private sedan from Newark airport to Philadelphia Airport are $220-$275 plus a 20% tip for the driver.

Reference source: My personal knowledge from being involved in the car/limo service business in the New Jersey area for over 25 years.

Disclosure: I own a car/limo service, but I do not provide transportation between Newark Airport and Philadelphia Airport.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for the clear disclosure.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options for getting from EWR to PHL.

One quite simple is to hire a car in Newark one-way and drive to Philadelphia airport - it's about 2 hours drive (Route 1 south and onto I-95 south straight to PHL).

Option two is to take Amtrak train from EWR airport (there's free shuttle from the terminal to the train station) to Philadelphia 30th street station and there change to SEPTA train to the airport.  Amtrak takes about 45-60 minutes, plus the SEPTA train another about 25 minutes. Amtrak is quite expensive though, depending on day/time, it may cost you $60-100 per person plus the SEPTA train to the airport.

If you want to save some more money, you can take New Jersey Transit train to Trenton. There change to SEPTA line to Philadelphia 30th street station and there change to SEPTA train to the airport.  It'll take you about 2 hours to Phila 30th street station with another about 25 minutes to the PHL airport - but it can be significantly cheaper than amtrak - probably, about $35-40 per person total cost.

Especially if there is more than one person travelling, cost-wise it could be best to just hire a car.  Depending on the day, it would cost probably under $100 (one-way is always more expensive).

P.S. I have done similar trips quite a few times when I lived in Philadelphia, but I left it in 2000.  The options are probably the same, but the prices are certainly different.

Comment: The express "Acela" Amtrak trains are much more expensive than the regular Amtrak trains, and the difference on this route is 15 minutes.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I think the difference is even less than 15 minutes - the regional one stops at Trenton, while Acela doesn't.

Comment: … and the Acelas do not stop at the EWR station, only in NWK (Newark Penn Station). So, you will have a Regional anyways.